# dynamic array list usage to iterate object Arraylist and obtain results base don object name

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, dataset

I have an object collection created in this way. What I need to do is to get a collection arranged by the name.

The object is

```
public class Object {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public Object(Integer id, String name, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
        //getters,setters
}
private static List<Object> populateObjList1(){
    List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object> ();
    Object obj1 = new Object(1, "aa", 4);
    Object obj2 = new Object(2, "bb", 3);
    Object obj3 = new Object(3, "cc", 7);
    Object obj4 = new Object(4, "dd", 6);
    Object obj5 = new Object(1, "aa", 2);
    Object obj6 = new Object(2, "cc", 1);
    Object obj7 = new Object(3, "ee", 5);
    Object obj8 = new Object(4, "ff", 7);
    Object obj9 = new Object(1, "bb", 3);
    Object obj10 = new Object(2, "cc", 4);
    Object obj11 = new Object(3, "dd", 7);
    Object obj12 = new Object(4, "ff", 1);
    objList.add(obj1);
    objList.add(obj2);
    objList.add(obj3);
    objList.add(obj4);
    objList.add(obj5);
    objList.add(obj6);
    objList.add(obj7);
    objList.add(obj8);
    objList.add(obj9);
    objList.add(obj10);
    objList.add(obj11);
    objList.add(obj12);
    return objList;
}
```

my code impl was -

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    List<Object> day1 = populateObjList1();
    List<String> abj = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println(""+abj.size());
    for (Object object : day1) {
        if(!abj.contains(object.getName())){
            abj.add(object.getName());
        }else{
            System.out.println("available");
        }
    }
    for (String string : abj) {
        System.out.println("__ "+string);
    }   
}

    *** The expected dataset should be *****
    **********************
    |Name | ** | ** | ** |
    **********************
    aa      4     2    - 
    **********************
    bb      3     -    3
    **********************
    cc      7     1    4
    **********************
    dd      6     -    7
    **********************
    ee      -     5    -
    **********************
    ff      -     7    1
    **********************
```

Comment: You should try `Map<K,List<V>>`

Comment: You really had to choose a class name identical to [the class from which all Java objects descend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: this is just a sample that i am trying.. that why I used the name Object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your design. I'd like suggest to use `Outer-Inner` class and `TreeSet`.

```
class Foo {
 private String name;
 private TreeSet<Item> items;

 public Foo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    items = new TreeSet<Item>();
 }
 public String getName() { return name; }
 public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
 public TreeSet<Item> getItems() {return items; }
 public void addItem(Integer id, Integer value) {
    items.add(new Item(id, value));
 }

 public class Item implements Comparable {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        Item i = (Item) arg0;
        if (id == i.id)
            return 0;
        else if (id > i.id)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    private Integer id;
    private Integer value;

    public Item(Integer id, Integer value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

}

And create objects of `Foo` and `Item`,

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
list.add(new Foo("aa"));
list.add(new Foo("bb"));
list.add(new Foo("cc"));
list.add(new Foo("dd"));

list.get(0).addItem(1, 4);
list.get(0).addItem(2, 2);
list.get(0).addItem(3, 3);
list.get(1).addItem(3, 1);
list.get(1).addItem(1, 1);
list.get(1).addItem(2, 8);
list.get(2).addItem(3, 3);
list.get(3).addItem(2, 10);
list.get(0).addItem(5, 10);

for (Foo foo : list) {
 System.out.print(foo.getName());
 Foo.Item[] ar = foo.getItems().toArray(new Foo.Item[0]);
 for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
   if (j >= ar.length)
    System.out.print(" - ");
   else if (ar[j].getId() == i) {
    System.out.print(" " + ar[j].getValue());
    j++;
   } else
        System.out.print(" - ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

`PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(10,comparator)`;

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the insertion methods (offer, poll, remove() and add) methods; linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).

Answer (score 1):

Have your `Object` implement [`Comparable<Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so...

```
public int compareTo(final Object other) {
  return name.compareTo(other.name);
}
```

Next, try to sort your `List<Object>` as follows, using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

```
Collections.sort(day1);
```

Now, `day1` should be sorted in lexicographic ascending order of names. If you want to be able to modify `day1` without having to re-sort, try using a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), i.e.

```
final TreeSet<Object> set = new TreeSet<>();
/* add here */
```

If you want to support multiple total orders (i.e. by id, or by value), consider decoupling the comparison from `Object` and create a distinct [`Comparator<Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead. Just specify the `Comparator` to either `sort` or the `TreeSet` constructor, depending on which you use.

Comment: how can the collection be dynamically created? do I have to use reflection in Java?